# unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'decimal.Decimal' and 'float' | Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, typeerror

Sometimes it works fine and sometimes it displays the error.

**ADMIN**

**models.py**

```
class BarterAdminWallet(models.Model):
    admin_wallet_id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    admin_wallet_balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=60, decimal_places=2, default = 0.00)
    admin_tokens_assigned = models.DecimalField(max_digits=60, decimal_places=2, default = 0.00)
    admin_tokens_earned = models.DecimalField(max_digits=60, decimal_places=2, default = 0.00)
    admin_tokens_bought = models.DecimalField(max_digits=60, decimal_places=2, default = 0.00)


class BarterAdminActionsTokens(models.Model):
    action_tokens_id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    account_activation_tokens = models.DecimalField(max_digits=30, decimal_places=2, default = 0.00)
    newsletter_subscription_tokens = models.DecimalField(max_digits=30, decimal_places=2, default = 0.00)
    name_tokens = models.DecimalField(max_digits=30, decimal_places=2, default = 0.00)
    surname_tokens = models.DecimalField(max_digits=30, decimal_places=2, default = 0.00)
    add_languages_tokens = models.DecimalField(max_digits=30, decimal_places=2, default = 0.00)
    mobile_phone_tokens = models.DecimalField(max_digits=30, decimal_places=2, default = 0.00)
    avatar_image_tokens = models.DecimalField(max_digits=30, decimal_places=2, default = 0.00)
    profile_description_tokens = models.DecimalField(max_digits=30, decimal_places=2, default = 0.00)
    dob_tokens = models.DecimalField(max_digits=30, decimal_places=2, default = 0.00)
    linkedin_profile_tokens = models.DecimalField(max_digits=30, decimal_places=2, default = 0.00)
    facebook_profile_tokens = models.DecimalField(max_digits=30, decimal_places=2, default = 0.00)
    address_1_tokens = models.DecimalField(max_digits=30, decimal_places=2, default = 0.00)
    address_2_tokens = models.DecimalField(max_digits=30, decimal_places=2, default = 0.00)
```

**USER**

**views.py**

```
   adminwallet = BarterAdminActionsTokens.objects.get()
   registration_tokens = adminwallet.account_activation_tokens

   adminwallet = BarterAdminWallet.objects.get()
   adminwallet.admin_wallet_balance = adminwallet.admin_wallet_balance - float(registration_tokens)
   adminwallet.admin_tokens_assigned = adminwallet.admin_tokens_assigned + float(registration_tokens)
   adminwallet.save()

   token_status.user_account_activation_token_status = "Awarded"
   token_status.save()
```

**CODE EXPLANATION**

- All fields related to maths are of the decimal.
- Same code, When calculating sometimes calculates perfectly and show error on some occasion.
- Also this code is working absolutely fine in other apps.

Comment: Isn't `registration_tokens` already a `Decimal`? Why do you typecast it before that calculation?

Comment: I tried that but did not worked.

Comment: Let me try that

Comment: It worked I should not have changed it then why It occurred in start

Answer (score 0):

As @Abdul Aziz pointed, that question should solve the issue.

You are adding `float` and `decimal.Decimal()` which might look similar, but are very different.

float gives you an approximation of the number you declare. For example, if you print 0.2 with 12 decimals places, you don’t actually get 0.2 but instead an approximation.

decimals on the other hand offer precision and Decimals can suffer from their own precision issues, but generally, decimals are more precise than floats.

```
   adminwallet.admin_wallet_balance = adminwallet.admin_wallet_balance - registration_tokens
   adminwallet.admin_tokens_assigned = adminwallet.admin_tokens_assigned + registration_tokens
```

Doing this alone should suffice.

Documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html

Comment: If you agree that the linked question solves the issue, please don't add an answer. If you have some better answer post it at that duplicate target. :)